# Google Fonts 'Rokkitt' not showing on IE11

Tags: css, font-face, internet-explorer-11, google-font-api

This website is failing to show the Google font 'Rokkitt' on IE11, it works fine on other browsers.

Is this down to the font developer or is it down to font-face issues in IE11?

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Website is found here: [CLICK HERE](http://partnersofprisoners.co.uk)

Answer (score 0):

The  problem is that your markup specifies IE8 emulation mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-EmulateIE8"></meta>
```

The Google font loader, though, only has access to the `User-Agent` string. It knows that the browser is IE11, but it doesn't know that your site has told the browser to behave like IE8. Thinking it's serving regular IE11, Google is only offering the font in `.woff` format. IE8 doesn't support `.woff`, so the browser (acting like IE8) ignores it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! Would you suggest removing the IE8 code from the head?

Comment: Since I don't know why you put it there in the first place, I cannot say.