# IE8 emulation mode in IE11 breaks Google font Playball

Tags: magento-1.4, internet-explorer-11, google-font-api, x-ua-compatible

[This Magento 1.4.1.1 website](http://www.a-et-a.com/) needs this markup:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-EmulateIE8"></meta>
```

to work under IE9 to IE11 (prototype compatibility reasons).
With IE9 all is fine (I can't test with IE10).
But with IE11, the google font Playball used mainly on the header is not shown correctly. IE11 shows an other unknown (for me) font.
This issue is directly connected with the specific markup because if I deactivate it all becomes fine. I red on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482115/google-fonts-rokkitt-not-showing-on-ie11):

> Google is only offering the font in .woff format. IE8 doesn't support
>   .woff, so the browser (acting like IE8) ignores it.

For the moment I use the normal Google API to be able to use this font, including:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playball' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
```

My question is:

- maintening the markup, is there a workaround, or another way to include the font on the website, to be able to show correctly the google fonts with IE11 (and other browsers, of course) ?

Answer (score 0):

I found an efficient workaround:

If your server is apache, you can replace this directive in the   by 2 lines on the .htaccess file at the root of your website:

```
BrowserMatch MSIE best-standards-support
Header set X-UA-Compatible IE=8 env=best-standards-support
```

With  this I have no more problems with Google fonts under IE10 or IE11 even emulating IE8.